# Big client.manifest.json size when building Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

When building my (medium-to-small scale) Nuxt project I get a warning about `../server/client.manifest.json` exceeding the recommended size, in my case it is 320KiB. Looking at the file I see thousands of lines with some random numbers and arrays.

What is this file and is it normal for it to be this big?